# Create shared shortcuts for Guest login

Tags: 12.04, automation, administration

I have decided to use Ubuntu as my base OS for my internet cafe machines, and also for the thin clients that connect to my Windows terminal server running 2008 R2. 8 machines in internet cafe room, and 8 in the teaching room. All run latest 12.04 LTS.

Fairly proficient with Linux admin, looking after the machines etc, but I have a question that I think needs some thought before I try to roll this out over all 16 machines

I am going to be using the Guest Login feature as it leaves no persistent data behind, and given the nature of losing power at least twice a week, it's nice to know it won't keep my customer's login details when we do lose electricity.

So, what I need is to configure the guest account to include some basic shortcuts, a pre-configured RDP shortcut for Rammia, that has the IP and colour depth and screen size details preconfigured, and for that to be available on every desktop as a persistent shortcut. Is this possible?

Second, I would like the machines to auto log on to the guest account.

Answer (score 1):

To autologin to an account, type this in a terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

now set

```
autologin-guest=true
```

and that's it!

Tested in Ubuntu 11.10...